# while Infinite loop in function

Tags: c++

```
bool isDigital(char c) { return ('0' <= c && c <= '9'); }

void DigitalToken( char digitToken[50], char ch ) {
    digitToken[0] = ch;
    char input = '\0';
    cin >> input;
    int i = 0;
    while ( ( input != ' ' ) && ( input != '\t' ) && ( input != '\n' ) ) { // got a infinite loop
        i++;
        digitToken[i] = input;
        cin >> input;
    } // while ( input != ' ' && input != '\t' && input != '\n' )
    
} // DigitalToken()

int main() {
  char ch = '\0';
  while ( cin >> ch ) {
    if ( isDigital(ch) ) {
      char* digitToken = new char[50]();
      DigitalToken(digitToken, ch);
      cout << digitToken;
      delete[] digitToken;
    } // else if
  } // while
} // main()
```

I don't understand why I got a infinite loop in `DitgitalToken` function.

When I input `123`, it should be output `123`.

I watched it for a long time, but I still don’t know why and how to fix it.

Comment: Instead of `cin >> input;` use `input = cin.get();`. Does it help?

Comment: @Arty Yes, but why can not use ```cin>>input```?

Comment: cin>>input handles newlines \n chars differently, it skips them, so if you typed `123` and hit enter then cin>>input will only read 3 chars 1 2 3 and then stop. But cin.get() will read 4 chars - 1 2 3 and newline \n exactly what you need in your code.

Comment: `bool isDigital(char c) { return std::isdigit(c); }`. Don't reinvent the wheel. Similarly, that `while ( (input != ' ' && input != '\t' && input != '\n')` can be just `while (!std::isspace(input))`.

Comment: @PeteBecker OK.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `cin >> input;` use `input = cin.get();`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful while using cin with characters or strings. It treats spaces, tabs, newlines as end of the input and hence do not treat them as input themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Your program blocks in the while loop on `cin >> input;` after it read "123".  As @Arty suggested use `cin.get()` instead as whitespace is stripped by default.  You can also use `cin >> noskipws;` prior to executing `cin >> input;`.  See [skipws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws).